# How to: Additional include Path for C++ Project in Visual Studio with CMake build System?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, arduino

when leaving the original Arduino IDE and switching to (for example) Visual Studio Code you can add project specific include path by adding lines to the

```
c_cpp_properties.json
```

that looks something like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/steven/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/**"
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Here I added the directory for Arduino header files so that VS Code is able to find definitions from the Arduino space.

Is there a way to do the same within the big brother Visual Studio IF the underlaying project is a CMake project and not a native VS project? If it was a native VS project I could add the directories by calling the project files property page. That seems not to be possible in CMake projects.
Would be great to make it even work in VS because of the more sophisticated options regarding code refactorings (e.g. if you use ReSharper++ or similar tools).

UPDATE:
For now I will use this solution:

```
# ========= Providing intellisense for Arduino =========

if(EXISTS "${ConfigurationsDir}/arduino.ini") # arduino.ini is ignored by git and need to be provided separately per environment
    SetConfigurationValuesByFile("${ConfigurationsDir}/arduino.ini") # read config file with Arduino paths and create key/value pairs from ini entries
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE allSourceFiles CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h")
    add_executable(IntellisenseProject EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${allSourceFiles}) # exclude this "fake" target from being build
    SetHeaderDirectories(ArduinoPackagesHeaderDirs ${ArduinoUserPackagesDir}) # read all directories from Arduino dir and subdirs where header files are located at
    SetHeaderDirectories(ArduinoLibrariesHeaderDirs ${ArduinoUserLibrariesDir})
    target_include_directories(IntellisenseProject PUBLIC ${ArduinoPackagesHeaderDirs} ${ArduinoLibrariesHeaderDirs} ${AllTargetsIncludeDirs})
endif()
```

This way I don't need to check in the environment settings (gitignore the arduino.ini) and have full intellisense for Arduino dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use

```
include_directories(C:/Users/steven/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/)
```

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/include_directories.html

But I won't recommend it since your project is now dependent of your machine setup...

You should try to create a FindArduino.cmake our create a Toolchain file IMHO...

Comment: Hi Mizux, thank you for sharing. I am still hesitating because include_directories means I need a target that uses these includes. But I don't want to build these files I want intellisense for (they will be compiled by Arduino CLI and the rest are google test targets where I use a different compiler). And of course the machine dependent setup is not quite what I want.